# Why can't I find my new classes in Project Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, class, package, project, visible

I created new classes by right clicking on a package. The package seems correct in the actual code in the classes, but the new classes can't be seen in the package in the Project Explorer.

What's going on?

Comment: Ok, noticed that some processes in Eclipse were frozen and quitting Eclipse got stuck in Saving workspace progress bar. That must've been the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem was that some processes, needed for updating the project explorer, in Eclipse were frozen and even quitting Eclipse wasn't possible without using Task Manager to destroy the Eclipse-process. Only after restarting my Windows 8 system I was able to continue using Eclipse normally.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project name in the Project Explorer and hit 'refresh'. I had this problem before too.

Comment: That usually works yes, but in this rare case I found the reason and put it in my answer.